# Magento 2 : Call Model Class in the default value for UpdateData.php

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, setup-upgrade, default-values

I have part of setup code in the setup/upgradeData.php to be like this :

```
 $dataSetup->addAttribute(
            'vendor', 'allowed_type', array(
                'group'             => 'General Information',
                'visible'           => true,
                'required'          => false,
                'global'            => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'type'              => 'text',
                'input'             => 'multiselect',

                'source'            => 'Test\Market\Model\Vendor\Attribute\Source\Offer',
                'backend'           => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend',
                'default'           => <some_of_values>,

                'label'             => 'Allowed Type',
                'sort_order'        => 300
            )
        );
```

then in the default part, I want to add value by calling model like this :

```
'default' => [VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Model\ClassName,
```

is it possible? if yes how can I write the class?

Comment: yes you can do it.

Comment: hi @John, could you explain and post it in the answer column :) ?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to add options then you have to call your model class into 'source' like :

```
'source' => 'VendorName\ModuleName\Model\Options'
```

Ans inside this model like :

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Model;

use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource;

class Options extends AbstractSource
{
    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        return [
            'option1' => [
                'label' => 'Option 1',
                'value' => 'option1'
            ],
            'option2' => [
                'label' => 'Option 2',
                'value' => 'option2'
            ],
            'option3' => [
                'label' => 'Option 3',
                'value' => 'option3'
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: hi @Hardik, thanks for your answer, but it's only for displaying multiselect options by source model,  then what I asked is,  this is possible to set default selected value by calling function in the model :) ?

Comment: Yes i think you can do it using config.xml, Using this file you can set default value for your system config field